# ImageMagick extension not available with this PHP installation

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am using Laravel 10 and my PHP Version => 8.2.12.

I am using Xampp for may project .I can not solve this error

```php
if ($request->hasFile('product_images')) {
    // $productImageModel = app(ProductsImage::class);
    // $imagePaths = $productImageModel->typeImage($request, $product_id);
    
    $manager = new ImageManager(new Driver());
    
    $name_gen = hexdec(uniqid()) . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $im = $manager->read($request->file('product_images'));
    $im = $im->resize(370, 246);
    $im->toJpeg(80)->save(base_path('public/front/images/products/large/' . $name_gen));
}
```

And the error:

> Intervention\Image\Exceptions\RuntimeException
> PHP 8.2.12
> 10.40.0
> ImageMagick extension not available with this PHP installation.